# SQL Dynamic Menu with Jquery

Tags: jquery, sql, stored-procedures, menu

I am trying to create a SQL driving menu to be implemented in to our site via jQuery.

The jQuery would ideally select from a stored procedure, and the stored procedure would create a list displaying all the parents, children, sub children menu items with a user field as well to limit permissions.

Does anyone have any experience and can assist in this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad and design related topic. It is not having one/straight answer.
what i can think of is

create Role table, Menu table, Submenu table , RoleMenuMapping table and MenuSubmenuMapping table.

In UI Side populate all the menu for the role from RoleMenuMapping table filter by RoleID. Similarly on click of a menu item , it should filter all the Submenus related to Clicked Menu from MenuSubmenuMapping table filter by MenuID.

This will keep the structure dynamic(database driven). Avoid using hardcodings in the code to keep the flexibility intact.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fair bit involved here.  First you need some sort of user permission system (likely either [Role Based Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) or a simple permissions scheme).

Once that's in place you need some sort of server side scripting to manage the user login, session state, etc.  jQuery is great, but it's client side.  You need to be standing on a server (PHP, ASP.NET, etc).  Your server code will interact with the database accordingly.

Design of a [hierarchical system in a database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) tends to be a bit more of an advanced topic, although if your nest levels are pre-determined it becomes a fair bit easier.

All in all, the question is far too broad for a direct answer.  There's too many supporting components involved and different ways to do it for us to say "do it like this."